# Display a background image that has the column layout for development

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

Are there any pre-build images that I could use when developing that will display a grid in the background of my browser?

This would make it easier to visualize the layout during development and make sure my design lines up correctly with a grid.

Does bootstrap have anything like this builtin that I can enable in the css?

Comment: You could create an image and place it as body background [960-Grid-System](https://github.com/nathansmith/960-Grid-System/blob/master/templates/photoshop/960_grid_12_col.psd)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you are looking for something like this?https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bootstrap-grid-overlay/mnlklmelflkheijccafopdohgclfefcg

Apologies if this is not what you are after.

Comment: yes exactly, except using css and an image, not a chrome ext.  interesting though thanks.